# Cannot get list of Projects from OnDemand Jira REST API + Basic Auth

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I seem to be getting intermittent results back from our OnDemand Jira instance's REST API.

If I properly set the Authorization header to '`Basic [base64login]`' & the Content-Type header to '`application/json`', and then issue a GET to `http://[installation].atlassian.net/rest/api/2/project` I get different results each time.

The first result always seems to be an empty JSON array (`[]`). Subsequent calls seem to work as expected for the most part, but occasionally I get an empty response. Also, if I enter invalid credentials I get an empty response rather than an error / 401 / etc.

Is there some gotcha to using Basic Auth on OnDemand instances? Does it require the additional use of cookies or something else?

Comment: That's odd that it's inconsistent. I'd try again using jira-python and dump the headers to see what it sends. You would usually authenticate first and then call the resource second